# INT data type values accepting CHAR datatype in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I am learning SQL. I am currently using PostgreSQL 12 and pgAdmin 6.1

It's accepting char type as integer. So there must be an implicit cast. Does implicit type casting are standard in mySQL, SQL Server?

DDL:

```
create table cars
(
    id serial,
    customerid int not null,
    employeeid int not null,
    model varchar(50) not null,
    status varchar(20) not null,
    totalcost int not null,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(customerid) references customers(id),
    foreign key(employeeid) references employees(id)
);
```

DML(Insert):

```
insert into cars(customerid,employeeid,model,status,totalcost)
values
('1','2','Ford F-150','READY',230);
```

Comment: It's using an [implicit type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of typecasting like

```
CAST ('100' AS INTEGER);
```

here, the value 100 is a string but it is considered an integer after applying the typecasting.